# rails new でエラー「invalid byte sequence in Windows-31J」がでます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

RubyとRailsをインストール後、[>rails new ---] で次のエラーが出ます。

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/rbreadline.rb:3908:in `codepoints': invalid byte sequence in Windows-31J　(ArgumentError)
```

`C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/rbreadline.rb`をクリックすると、コンソール画面 が一瞬現れてすぐ消えます。`invalid byte sequence`を少し調べてみたのですがよくわかりません。宜しくお願いします。

環境

- Windows10 Home
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
- rails 5.1.6

今回は[このサイト](https://www.225-futures-trader.com/2017/10/171004-ruby-tradingsystem-backtest-programming.html)を参考にしています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows のエンコーディングの問題です。

今回の場合、Ruby のデフォルト外部エンコーディングの設定が [Windows-31J](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8932) に設定されているのに、外部ファイルのエンコーディングが Windows-31J ではなかった (おそらく UTF-8 になっている) ためにエラーが出ています。

Ruby に外部エンコーディングが UTF-8 だと教えてあげればよいので、`set RUBYOPT=-EUTF-8` などで設定すれば直ります ([参考1](http://sugamasao.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/08/24/224521)、[2](https://hail2u.net/blog/webdesign/setting-rubyopt-for-sass.html))。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。