# rails s で sqlite3関連の (LoadError) がでます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42963/19110)に引き続きお世話になります。

今度は、`rails s` で次のエラーがでます。

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

`C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb`をクリックすると、一瞬コンソールが現れてすぐ消えます。

昨日、Rubyをアンインストールし、関連フォルダも削除し、再度Rubyをインストールしました。
今回は次のサイトを参考にしています。 https://www.225-futures-trader.com/2017/10/171004-ruby-tradingsystem-backtest-programming.html

sqlite3のインストールについては、そのサイトの手順で行いました。

```
ridk exec pacman -Ss sqlite3　で検索
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
gem install sqlite3 --platform ruby
```

現在確認すると、

- mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3 3.21.0-1 [インストール済み]
- msys/libsqlite 3.19.3.0-2 (libraries) [インストール済み]

です。
宜しくお願いします。

- Windows10　Home
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
- Rails 5.1.6

以下、rails s の結果です。

```
>rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
        22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        17: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        10: from C:/Users/〇〇〇〇/map/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

以下は sqlite3 の検索です。

```
>ridk exec pacman -Ss sqlite3
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-lua51-lsqlite3 0.9.3-1
    LuaSQLite is a Lua 5 binding to allow users/developers to manipulate SQLite
    2 and SQLite 3 databases (through different implementations) from lua
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python2-sqlitedict 1.5.0-1
    Persistent dict, backed by sqlite3 and pickle, multithread-safe (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python3-sqlitedict 1.5.0-1
    Persistent dict, backed by sqlite3 and pickle, multithread-safe (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-sqlite3 3.21.0-1
    A C library that implements an SQL database engine (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-lua51-lsqlite3 0.9.3-1
    LuaSQLite is a Lua 5 binding to allow users/developers to manipulate SQLite
    2 and SQLite 3 databases (through different implementations) from lua
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-sqlitedict 1.5.0-1
    Persistent dict, backed by sqlite3 and pickle, multithread-safe (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-sqlitedict 1.5.0-1
    Persistent dict, backed by sqlite3 and pickle, multithread-safe (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3 3.21.0-1 [インストール済み]
    A C library that implements an SQL database engine (mingw-w64)
msys/libsqlite 3.19.3.0-2 (libraries) [インストール済み]
    Sqlite3 library
msys/libsqlite-devel 3.19.3.0-2 (development)
    Sqlite3 headers and libraries
msys/sqlite 3.19.3.0-2
    A C library that implements an SQL database engine
msys/sqlite-doc 3.19.3.0-2
    Most of the static HTML files that comprise this website, including all of
    the SQL Syntax and the C/C++ interface specs and other miscellaneous
    documentation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32\lib\sqlite3\` に `2.5` というディレクトリがないと思います。
sqlite3 の x64-mingw32 用 gem がまだ ruby 2.5 に対応していないということです。
今のところはまだ ruby 2.4 系を使っておくのが良いと思います。

また、`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby` で `C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.13` (`-x64-mingw32` でなく) にインストールされ、sqlite3_native.so も作られるようですが、rails からは使われないようです。

Comment: 解決しました！　再びRubyアンインストール・ファルダ削除し、　Ruby 2.4.4 をインストール、>gem install sqlite3 で「Yay! You're on Rails!」が表示されました。　ほんと有難うございました！!